# TensorFlow 1.3 GPU version not working on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, tensorflow

I am a beginner to machine learning, and am trying to set up a TensorFlow python environment using Anaconda. However, I have been dealing with the common problem of    "No module named "pywrap_tensorflow_internal""

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in im
port_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in im
port_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init_
_.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in im
port_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_
tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in im
port_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

Despite this being the same error as so many other questions present, none of the solutions seem to work.
I have `MSVCP140.DLL` installed and pointed to in my `%PATH%` and I'm running this on Python 3.5. I believe the problem to lie within the CUDA, as this problem does not arise when I run the CPU version of TensorFlow

However, I've had difficulty figuring out what's wrong with my CUDA setup. I installed CUDA 8 and cuDNN v5.1. [Here is what my CUDA install folder looks like. cuDNN is just the files extracted from the cuDNN zip.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2stj.png)

In addition, here are the relevant parts of my my `%PATH%`:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\cudaNN\bin\cudnn64_5.dll;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\cudaNN\include\cudnn.h;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\cudaNN\lib\x64\cudnn.lib;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\lib;
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;
```

I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with my setup, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed the GPU version of TensorFlow 1.3 (which was released yesterday), the released PIP package requires **cuDNN 6**. You can install it from [NVIDIA's website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn). Make sure that the directory containing the file `cudnn64_6.dll` is included in your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: Interesting, the tensorflow manual said to only use cuDNN 5.1, but i'll try out using cuDNN 6 on a fresh install. I hope this works

Comment: Indeed, the manual for TF 1.3 has a mistake in it, and I have a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/12383) out to fix it. The [TF 1.3 release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.3.0) mention the change to using cuDNN 6 in prebuilt binaries.

Comment: Update: this worked! thank you so much for the help. I wonder why the installation instructions said to use a verions of cuDNN that didn't work?

Comment: thanks i was searching for hours and couldnt get it to work